# How to conditionally render text within react-i18next trans component

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

So I have the following trans component

```
<Trans i18nKey="userManagement:description">
    <span className="accountList-number">{{ accountsInvited }}</span>
    {' '}
    User(s) Invited,
    {' '}
    <span className="accountList-number">{{ accountsRegistered }}</span>
    {' '}
    User(s) Registered,
    {' '}
    <span className="accountList-number">{{ accountsAllowed }}</span>
    User(s) Allowed
</Trans>
```

with the corresponding `userManagement.json` translation file having the following line

```
{
    ...
    "description": "<0>{{accountsInvited}}</0> User(s) Invited, <4>{{accountsRegistered}}</4> User(s) Registered, <8>{{accountsAllowed}}</8> User(s) Allowed",
    ...
}
```

[It displays like so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbI4D.png)

I would like to actually make the "N user allowed" clause conditionally rendered. If accountsAllowed is null, then I would not show this clause since there is no limit on the number of users, but otherwise it should get displayed. On the react side, I suppose a good old `?:` operator solves my problem, but I do not know how to change the translation file to also be conditional. Any helps would be appreciated. We are using trans component since those numbers are custom-styled and I prefer preserving the trans component if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context prop might be helpful.
https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#trans-props

I didn't test the below code, so it may not work as expected

```js
<Trans i18nKey="userManagement:description" context={accountsAllowed ? "with-accountsAllowed" : null}>
    <span className="accountList-number">{{ accountsInvited }}</span>
    {' '}
    User(s) Invited,
    {' '}
    <span className="accountList-number">{{ accountsRegistered }}</span>
    {' '}
    User(s) Registered
    {accountsAllowed 
       ? (
         {', '}
         <span className="accountList-number">{{ accountsAllowed }}</span>
         User(s) Allowed
       )
       : '.'
    }
</Trans>
```

```json
{
    ...
    "description": "<0>{{accountsInvited}}</0> User(s) Invited, <4>{{accountsRegistered}}</4> User(s) Registered, <8>{{accountsAllowed}}</8> User(s) Allowed",
    "description_with-accountsAllowed": "<0>{{accountsInvited}}</0> User(s) Invited, <4>{{accountsRegistered}}</4> User(s) Registered.
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am looking for. For future reference, the code posted as-is does not work because there can only be 1 parent JSX element and there were 3 in the code: ```{', '}```, ```<span ...>...</span>```, and ```User(s) Allowed```. One solution is to wrap them in a ```React.Fragement```, or in my case, to preserve the numbering, I did conditional rendering on all three elements.